# Сообщение "your session has timed out"

Tags: сессия, веб-программирование

Что дeлать, когда появляется окно

> your session has timed  out

при работе на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Сеанс посещения окончен. Сайт имеет преимущество time out (проще, обращайтесь к модератору сайта).

Comment: Или же не хватает скорости инета